# Global try catch

Tags: c#, silverlight, try-catch, global

I know try catch have been discussed a lot but I haven’t found a solution to my problem yet.

I’m writing a Silverlight application where every exception should generate a  MessageBox that says something like “Sorry of the inconvenience”.

Since I cannot guarantee that my code will be free from exceptions my coworker has instructed me to have a try catch in every method (a couple of hundred) like this:

```
public void Method1()
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, we apologize for the inconvenience. \n" + e.Message);
    }
}

public void Method2()
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, we apologize for the inconvenience. \n" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

But it seems so excessive. I’ve read that one does not use try catch in this way plus there will be a lot of duplicated code plus the code will be obfuscated and hard to read.

Are there any alternatives like a global try catch I can use?

Comment: You **don't** want to catch every exception where it occurs. It may make sense to have a few such handlers high up the call stack (the error message is useless though). But swallowing exceptions for no good reason is a very bad idea.

Comment: If you don't know how to handle the exception, why are you showing a message box only? You should terminate the application as it is now in an unknown state (say this exception is an `OutOfMemoryException`, do you really want to try and keep running?).

Comment: @Oded The majority of exceptions are non-fatal, but one rarely knows how to handle them in the very same method that raises it. If the application terminated every time an exception was raised that can't be handled in the same place, we couldn't even launch many applications, much less do anything wrong with them. The sane thing to do is letting the exception bubble up to someone who either (1) knows how to handle it or (2) knows there's no one higher up who knows.

Comment: @delnan He didnt say to terminate on every exception.  But the OP should NOT be catching every generic exception and just showing a messagebox, leaving the user with a broken unresponsive program at times.

Comment: @delnan - My point is about global exception handlers (top level ones) trying to do pokemon exception handling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can always handle the [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Which should be noted is still a bad practice to show a message box for any exception(especially ones that need to terminate the application instead)

Comment: UI Preference it probably is not the most professional thing to do this is true.

Comment: bad practice to show a message box for any exception? why ?

Comment: in a user environment user doesn't know what it means and it can just confuse them more

Answer (score 7):

Try-catches in each and single method is silly. But:

What is the reason your colleague wants you to catch exceptions to that extent? Do you let exceptions slip through to a level where they are unwanted?

I had a similar case with a product already in use with our customers. It was a WPF project that is similar to silverlight. My job was to ride out bugs in old bad code, that nobody still working with us mastered. The application cross-function with other programs in windows and it was impossible to foresee what could go wrong in different environments.

I had these **problems**:

1. **The program stopped working because of uncaught exceptions.**
2. It was hard to understand what went wrong, in order to fix the bugs. Our customers normally report errors by emailing screen dumps where it was hard to see what happened.

My **approach** was:

1. Catching exceptions on *selected* "user and system end points". That is typically event handlers for button click, drag-n-drop, navigation commands, and so on from the user side, and typically windows messages and server responses from the system side.
2. A class `OopsBox` to make the unexpected error handling a one-liner in each catch. Each catch has an as friendly message as possible, and hides the dirty stuff behind an expand button. The box is also used for error messages for *expected* errors, and in those cases there is no expand button and no dirty stuff to display as we know what went wrong already.
   [image: OopsBox]

We **gained** this:

- Users had an easier time figuring out a workaround, as they were not thrown out of context, in cases when the error were not severe.
- It was, and still is, easier to grasp what went wrong when some unexpected behaviour was reported.
- The Oops boxes started out in large frequencies but I believe the product is stabilizing faster now, and the Oops-boxes are much rarer.
- Still to this day, when something goes wrong at a customer's, I get the call stack from them in an email. :)

It **cost** this:

- A large walk-through of all the user and system end points.
- Some logic had to be re-written to be able to put the catches at the right places.

### Summary

- Exceptions should be caught before they do any damage, like throwing the user out of context, and in a level where it makes sense.
- When users run your program and something unexpected happens, make sure you have a way to point you to where to start looking. I did this by catching otherwise unhandled exceptions on "user and system end points" that I selected for this purpose.
- Error box or not, try to find a way to not throw the user out of context when something goes wrong. It is hard to make it work in all cases though, but it is fatal when it happens.

Answer (score 6):

You can capture unhanded (and thread) exceptions using the Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException properties.

Your Main would look something like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() { 

    if (Debugger.IsAttached) {
        Run();
        return;
    } 

    Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
    Run();
}
```

Note the debugger check, just so the debugger can catch these exceptions when your developing.

The Run function is pretty simple

```
    static void Run() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

And then the two exception handlers.

```
    static void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e) {
        ErrorInformationDialog eid = new ErrorInformationDialog(e.Exception.Message, e.Exception);
        eid.ShowDialog();
    }

    static void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        ErrorInformationDialog eid = new ErrorInformationDialog(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        eid.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And ErrorInformationDialog is just a form I put together to display an error notification and give instructions for reporting it.